# Desplegar un div al pulsar una imagen

Tags: jquery

Buenas intento hacer un desplegable y me estoy pegando bastantes golpes con él. He escrito este código `JQuery`, pero no funciona, (cosa que no me extraña porque es el primero hecho por mí xD).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // 1) Inicialmente ocultamos la flecha de contraer acordeón. Inicialmente está contraido.
  $("#arrow-up").css("display", "none");

  // 2) Inicialmente acordeón contraido, (altura=0)
  $(".Marca_General_Acordeon").css("height", "0px");

  // Si se presiona la flecha hacia abajo (=desplegar)
  if ($("arrow-down").click) {

    //Ocultamos esta, mostramos la contraria y le damos altura a Marca_General_Acordeon
    $(".Marca_General_Acordeon").css("height", "500px");
    $("#arrow-down").css("display", "none");
    $("#arrow-up").css("display", "block");
  }

  // Por el contrario, si está despelgado (= la flecha visible es arrow-up)
  else {

    //Ocultamos esta, mostramos la contraria y le damos altura a Marca_General_Acordeon
    $(".Marca_General_Acordeon").css("height", "0px");
    $("#arrow-up").css("display", "none");
    $("#arrow-down").css("display", "block");
  }

});
```

```css
.Marca_General_Acordeon {
  height: 0px;
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: auto;
}

.Marca_Flechas_Acordeon_General {
  width: 1100px;
  /* Molaria saber como centrar el interior y que esta media fuese % */
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.Flechas_Acordeon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<HTML lang="es">

<HEAD>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <div class="Marca_General_Acordeon">

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/Alpine100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AstonMartin100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="Marca_Flechas_Acordeon_General">

    <img src="Img/Iconos/AA_FlechaCirculo_Arriba.png" id="arrow-up" class="Flechas_Acordeon" />
    <img src="Img/Iconos/AA_FlechaCirculo_Abajo.png" id="arrow-down" class="Flechas_Acordeon" />

  </div>


  <!-- Llamada a JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Motor.js"></script>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Los comentarios que observais, es exactamente lo que quiero que haga.
Es decir,

1. Como tengo dos flechas, (hacia arriba y hacia abajo), inicialmente solo quiero que se vea la que apunta hacia abajo, puesto que inicialmente está recogido el desplegable.
2. Por el mismo motivo defino que la altura del desplegable es 0.
3. Si se presiona una flecha tiene que:

   a) Ocultar esta.

   b) Hacer aparecer la contraria.

   c) Tiene que dar una altura de 0px o de 500px en función de si se esta desplegando (se ha pulsado felcha hacia abajo) o recogiendo (se ha pulsado flecha hacia arriba).

He visto que existe el `.slideToggle` que quizás serviría para sustituir el tema de poner alturas.

Un saludo y no me mateis si hay muchos fallos. ¿Puede ser que el error sea que cojo mal el click en la flecha? (Esta es una imagen, lo digo por si tuviese alguna repercusión)

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código HTML por favor? La pregunta está muy bien redactada pero necesitamos poder reproducir tu error para poderte dar una solución más acorde a tu problema. Si presionas Cntrl+M sobre la pregunta te dejará insertar código de una manera mucho más sencilla y te permite hacer un snippet ejecutable dentro de la misma. Saludos :)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el fallo? Sólo veo un evento de click en arrow-down y ninguno en arrow-up, ¿podría ser este el problema?

Comment: Estas utilizando mal el evento **click** de jquery, deberia ser algo asi: $( "#id" ).click(function() { // hacer algo }); puedes encontrar más informacion en la documentacion: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @FranciscoRomero Añadido todo el código! No se como hacer como salgan las imágenes. En el rectangulo más fino (rojo) se supone están las flechas de contraer y estirar el div.

Comment: @Nache Efectivamente solo ves ese porque al poner un `if else`, pensé que no hace falta, pero quizás sí...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reemplaza por lo eventos `click` de cada boton:

```
// Si se presiona la flecha hacia abajo (=desplegar)
$("#arrow-down").click(function(){
    //Ocultamos esta, mostramos la contraria y le damos altura a Marca_General_Acordeon
    $(".Marca_General_Acordeon").css("height","500px");
    $("#arrow-down").css("display","none");
    $("#arrow-up").css("display","block");

// Por el contrario, si está despelgado (= la flecha visible es arrow-up)
$("#arrow-up").click(function(){
    //Ocultamos esta, mostramos la contraria y le damos altura a Marca_General_Acordeon
    $(".Marca_General_Acordeon").css("height","0px");
    $("#arrow-up").css("display","none");
    $("#arrow-down").css("display","block");
});
```

con **slideToogle**:

```
.Marca_General_Acordeon {
    height: 500px;
    width: 1100px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: auto;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    // 1) Iniciialmente ocultamos la flecha de contraer acordeón. Inicialmente está contraido.
    $("#arrow-up").css("display","none");

    // 2) Inicialmente acordeón contraido, 
    $( ".Marca_General_Acordeon" ).slideToggle( "slow" );

    // Si se presiona la flecha hacia abajo (=desplegar)
    $("#arrow-down").click(function(){
        //Ocultamos esta, mostramos la contraria y le damos altura a Marca_General_Acordeon
        $( ".Marca_General_Acordeon" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $("#arrow-down").css("display","none");
        $("#arrow-up").css("display","block");
    });

    // Por el contrario, si está despelgado (= la flecha visible es arrow-up)
    $("#arrow-up").click(function(){
        //Ocultamos esta, mostramos la contraria y le damos altura a Marca_General_Acordeon
        $( ".Marca_General_Acordeon" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
        $("#arrow-up").css("display","none");
        $("#arrow-down").css("display","block");
    });

    });
```

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado. Una pregunta si no es mucha molestia. ¿Porque en el `css` hay que poner una altura? Lo estoy comprobando y veo que con 0 no funciona, pero no entiendo el motivo. GRACIAS.

Comment: SlideToogle trabaja con `css display`, para para mostrar u ocultar, no modifica el `height` ya que no es necesario para ocultar el `div`, entonces si lo dejas en `height:0px`, estara visible pero no podras verlo porque no tiene altura.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás algo así te sirva. Capturas un sólo evento de click, en el que están las dos flechas. Según la clase que contenga determinas si está cerrado o abierto y actúas en consecuencia. Puedes añadir efectos de animación a show y a hide para que sea más visual.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.arrows').click(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('a-closed')) {
        $(this).removeClass('a-closed');
        $(this).addClass('a-opened');
        $(".Marca_General_Acordeon").show();
        $("#arrow-down").hide();
        $("#arrow-up").show();
     } else {
        $(this).addClass('a-closed');
        $(this).removeClass('a-opened');
        $(".Marca_General_Acordeon").hide();
        $("#arrow-down").show();
        $("#arrow-up").hide();
     }
  });

});
```

```css
.Marca_General_Acordeon {
  display: none;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: auto;
}

.Marca_Flechas_Acordeon_General {
  width: 1100px;
  /* Molaria saber como centrar el interior y que esta media fuese % */
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.Flechas_Acordeon {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#arrow-down {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<HTML lang="es">

<HEAD>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <div class="Marca_General_Acordeon">

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/Alpine100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AstonMartin100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="Marca_Individual">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AlfaRomeo100px.png" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="Marca_Flechas_Acordeon_General">
    <div class="arrows a-closed">
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AA_FlechaCirculo_Arriba.png" id="arrow-up" class="Flechas_Acordeon" />
      <img src="Img/Iconos/AA_FlechaCirculo_Abajo.png" id="arrow-down" class="Flechas_Acordeon" />
   </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Llamada a JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Motor.js"></script>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var $btns = $('.btn');
var $imagen = $('#imagen');

$btns.click(function(e) {
  var id = this.id=="up";
 
    $(this).siblings().show();
    $(this).hide();
    
    $imagen.css('padding-top', 
      id ? '0em' : '5em'
    );
});
});
```

```css
#imagen{
 position: realtive;
 background-color: darkmagenta;
 padding: 4em;
}

.buttons{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  right: 0.5em;
}

#down {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="imagen">
 <span class="buttons">
  <span class="btn" id="up">
    &#x25B2;
  </span>
  <span class="btn" id="down">
    &#x25BC;
  </span>
 </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```